# unit test for Map computeIfAbsent method

Tags: java, junit, java-8, mockito

How I can write a Junit for `Map` `computeIfAbsent` method. I have below code -

```
CompletableFuture<Employee>[] employeeDetailFutures =
        empIds.stream().map(empId ->
        employeeCache.computeIfAbsent(empId, k -> employeeService.employeeDetails(Integer.valueOf(empId))))
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);
```

Here `employeeCache` is an `Map` and I want to write a Junit for `employeeCache.computeIfAbsent(...)` so far I have tried below but every time looks like new map is creating and getting null

```
Map<String, CompletableFuture<Employee>> mockMap;
@Before
public void setUp() {
    this.mockMap = Mockito.mock(Map.class);
} 

when(mockMap.computeIfAbsent(any(), any()).thenReturn(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Employee Object);
```

Every time I am getting null value for `computeIfAbsent`. What I am missing here.

Comment: where is the `Employee Object` (object) initialised?

Comment: `.thenReturn(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Employee Object)` is not even valid Java syntax.

Comment: is mockMap getting injected somplace?